# How to update a bound variable in a sidebar in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a design where there is a sidebar, and a header and content gets updated based on `ng-view`. sidebar and header are templates.

This is how it looks

[image]

The number next to Colors denotes the total colors. It is coded like this:

```
  <a ng-href="#/colors"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Colors {{totalColors}}</a>
```

When a user adds a color, I redirect the user to the main colors page which lists the total number of colors (received from the server). I redirect the user like this:

```
  djangoAuth.addColor(dataModel)
  .then(function(data) {
    $location.path("/colors");
  }, function(data) {
    //error
  })
```

and the number received from the server is coded like this:

```
  djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data){
    $scope.model = data;
    $scope.totalColors = computeTotalColors(data.profile.all_colors);
  });
```

**Question**

The problem is that when I click "Add", the number in the sidebar does not get updated. I'm not sure why this is happening, because the `totalColors` variable does get updated when it is showed on `/colors` page. It just isn't updated on the sidebar. Sidebar and `/colors` page both have `ng-controller="ColorCtrl"`

Comment: There is not enough information, but if it is as i suppose and you have nested scopes, try putting totalColors not directly in the $scope but in an new object under the $scope like $scope.yourObject.totalColors , so that it can be retrieved from inheritance chain.